# Should refs be in listed as dependencies for useEffect and such?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

As I understand, the containers returned by useRef are always the same - yet referencing them in useEffect and similar functions results in eslint exhaustive-deps warning. Is it safe to ignore the warning in this case, and what's a good way to avoid both clogging the output log with warnings, and my code with disable-line comments? Or should I just stick them into dependency list to keep eslint happy?

Answer (score 7):

When `useRef` is first called it creates an object with a `current` property. This object will remain the same across subsequent renders. Ie: the reference to this object won't change.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

[image]

So it's safe to omit it from the dependencies array.

See the code below (also available in the Sandbox link):

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-dhawan-ys267?file=/src/App.js

```
const someRef = useRef({foo: "bar"});
let x = 1;

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(someRef.current.foo);
  console.log(x);
}, []);              // THERE IS A WARNING HERE FOR THE "x"
```

`eslint/exhaustive-deps` is only worrying about the `x`, and not the `someRef.current.foo`.

[image]

**NOTE:** I've just put the `x` there to make sure the warnings were being triggered by eslint.

The reason behind this is that `useRef` isnot related to the render cycle. I mean, it's not recreated, neither is automatically updated after every render, like state, props or variables created during render usually are.

Are you sure you are getting this warning for `useRef`? See the CodeSandbox link and give it a double check. Check how are you referencing them into the `useEffect` and also check your React and Eslint/plugin versions.