# useRef passed in as parameter needs to be added to dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, use-ref, usecallback

From the following two questions, I understand that `useRef` does not need to add update dependencies.

Related questions I looked at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476525/9854149
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353582/9854149

But when `useRef` is used as `props`, `eslint` always warns about `hook` missing dependencies?

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const One = ({ refEl }) => {
  const clickHandler = useCallback(e => {
    refEl.current = 1111;
  }, []); //⚠️ React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'refEl'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

  useEffect(() => {
    refEl.current = 2222;
  }, []); //⚠️ React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'refEl'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

  return (
    <div onClick={clickHandler} ref={refEl}>
      One
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const el = useRef('');
  return <One refEl={el} />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: refEl is passed as props, not parameter

Answer (score 0):

eslint can't tell that refEl is a ref so it will just consider it as an ordinary prop to pass a ref down to a functional component you should use React.forwardRef

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, forwardRef } from "react";

const One = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const clickHandler = useCallback((e) => {
    ref.current = 1111;
  }, [ref]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = 2222;
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div onClick={clickHandler} ref={ref}>
      One
    </div>
  );
});

function App() {
  const el = useRef("");
  return <One ref={el} />;
}

export default App;
```